# Embed a video in facebook comment or wall

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, youtube

Is there any way to embed a video or video link in facebook wall or comment?

It the video link belongs to youtube it show a preview.

For ex:-

How can I do this with other urls for ex:-

http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

Hope my question is understandable. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer, yes we can

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Cartoon Tom and Jerry 2015"/>
                <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
                <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/x2jae3a?autoPlay=1"/>
                <meta property="og:video:width" content="640"/>
                <meta property="og:video:height" content="360"/>
                <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jae3a"/>
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="Dailymotion"/>
                <meta property="og:type" content="video"/>
                <meta property="og:image" content="http://s2.dmcdn.net/JWZve/526x297-dbz.jpg"/>
                <meta property="og:description" content="Friends for more New Tom &amp; Jerry Cartoon in English Urdu &amp; Hindi Visit http://aboutechno.com/category/tom-jerry-cartoon/     Cartoon Tom and Jerry 2015,Cartoon Tom &amp; Jerry 2015,Watch Free Tom and Jerry,online Tom and Jerry cartoon,watch free Full Tom and Jerry cartoon,online live Tom and Jerry cartoon,2015 Tom and Jerry cartoon,free watch live Tom and Jerry 2015"/>
                <meta property="video:duration" content="375"/>
                <meta property="video:director" content="http://www.dailymotion.com/farhanayub"/>
                <meta property="video:release_date" content="2015-03-12T07:49:28+01:00"/>
                <meta property="video:tag" content="Free 2015 cartoon"/>
```